# BEM naming and positioning

Tags: css, sass, bem

I'm new to BEM and i'm trying to implement this:

```
.details-header {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  display: block;

  &__heading-panel {
    margin-top: 10px; 
  }

  &__heading {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Defining the same `margin-top` inside `details-header__heading-panel` is wrong, i know, but because there is element between details-header and details-header__heading-panel, i need this margin, how do i solve this, and also keep the code DRY?

EDIT: Here is the html:

```
<div class="details-header">
        <div>Something</div>
        <div class="details-header__heading-panel">
            <h1 class="details-header__heading">
                <span>something</span>
            </h1>
            <a>
                Link
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need margin between that div between `details-header` and `details-header__heading-panel`

Comment: can you also provide your html code so we can help you further.
and what element is that between details-header and details-header__heading-panel

Comment: @davecar21i updated the quesiton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with defining the same margin-top inside `details-header` and `details-header__heading-panel`. Just keep going with your original code.
It's not copy-paste but just coincidence.